# C++ - Using a map to store callback functions

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, callback

I'm attempting to use a map to store functions to be called at certain times.

```
typedef std::function<void(rapidjson::Document&)> Callback;

std::map<std::string, Callback> _callbackDict = {
    { "foo", HandleFoo },
    { "bar", HandleBar },
};
```

When I attempt to store them it leads to an error:

```
error: could not convert '{{"foo", ((FooBar*)this)->FooBar::HandleFoo}, {"bar", ((FooBar*)this)->FooBar::HandleBar}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::function<void(int, int)> >'
```

### MCVE

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void(int, int)> Callback;
class FooBar
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, Callback> _callbackDict = {
        { "foo", HandleFoo },
        { "bar", HandleBar },
    };
public:
    FooBar();
    void HandleFoo(int a, int b);
    void HandleBar(int a, int b);
    ~FooBar();

};
```

Comment: ^^^ These need to be `static` member or global functions just to note.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've included code which reproduces the error stated in the question.

Comment: @J.Doe It's the issue I mentioned in my 1st comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's **still** not clear exactly what you're trying to do.  The *smallest* change to get your code to compile was already given in a comment; make your functions `static`:

```
namespace rapidjson {   struct Document; }

typedef std::function<void(int, int)> Callback;
class FooBar
{
    std::map<std::string, Callback> _callbackDict = {
        { "foo", HandleFoo },
        { "bar", HandleBar },
    };
public:
    static void HandleFoo(int a, int b);
    static void HandleBar(int a, int b);
};
```

But you really need to get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read it; this is supposed to be a Q-and-A site, not help-me-with-my-code.

Answer (score 3):

The following code compiles:

```
namespace rapidjson { struct Document; }

void HandleFoo(rapidjson::Document&) {}
void HandleBar(rapidjson::Document&) {}    

typedef std::function<void(rapidjson::Document&)> Callback;
std::map<std::string, Callback> _callbackDict = {
    { "foo", HandleFoo },
    { "bar", HandleBar },
};
```

Note that `FooBar::Run()` isn't relevant to your problem and doesn't need to be included in your question.